# Is there a specific order for completing the Moon Phase rooms in the penultimate level?

Tags: prince-of-persia-forgotten-sands

In *Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands* on the DS, the penultimate level includes a set of 5 Moon Phase rooms.  Is there a specific order in which these rooms have to be completed to allow the player to continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a 'right' order for these rooms. If you enter a room in the *right order*, you'll just get teleported back to the corridor. If you enter a room in the *wrong order*, you have to get through the room and start the sequence again.

The right sequence is:

- D-shaped half moon
- C-shaped crescent
- Opposite crescent
- Opposite half moon
- Full moon

Answer (score 1):

I haven't noticed the moon or the order!!

I followed the sound. When circling through the corridor, you hear some sound in between two adjacent doors and that doesn't happen between all the adjacent doors. It's been a while, you have to take one of these two doors(It must be the one behind, if you are circling clockwise, i.e, left to right) every time.

The above might be confusing, but the sound is the key! I have to check this moon order though.